# Liquibase don't log errors on constraint violation

Tags: liquibase

I'm working on a spring boot application where we are using liquibase to keep up to date the DB.
We have a scenario when we import some JSON data, which is kept as varchar into a table on SQL Server. This JSON contains UI configurations and sometimes the developers forget to check if the JSON is valid before importing the data, resulting on errors in UI because of invalid JSON.

In order to prevent this kind of errors we added a constraint on DB level to make sure the data contains only valid JSON, but when we run the application, 
using an invalid JSON, there is no crash or errors logged - SQL error is silently ignored.

My liquibase changeset:

```
<changeSet author="my.name" id="02_my_script" runOnChange="true" failOnError="true" >
    <sqlFile dbms="h2, oracle, mssql" encoding="utf8"
        endDelimiter="\nGO"
        path="classpath:sql/02_my_script.sql"
        relativeToChangelogFile="false" splitStatements="true" stripComments="true"/>
```

02_my_script.sql - contains a sql script which contains a JSON, something like this (I cannot use the real json):

```
DELETE FROM My_Table WHERE ID = 1;
INSERT INTO My_Table (Json)
VALUES ('{
    "name" : "Test"
    "firstName" : "ABC"
}');
```

The constraint on My_Table:

```
ALTER TABLE My_Table ADD CONSTRAINT Chk_JSON_is_json CHECK (ISJSON(Json) > 0)
```

If I try to run the script directly on the DB then I get an error as expected.

Is there a setting we can use in order to make liquibase show an error when there is a constraint violation ? Or maybe a configuration just to log the error in a log file?

Liquibase version I use is 3.5.3

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Does your database actually throw an exception when you do that? Maybe it's not Liquibase but your DBMS that simply doesn't validate the JSON

Comment: The database I user is SQL Server 2016.
The database throws an error if I try to execute the same script directly on DB.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug reported in [Liquibase Jira](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2942) related to this behavior.

I did a little bit of debug in Liquibase source code and I found in JdbcExecutor.ExecuteStatementCallback#doInStatement method a call 
stmt.execute(statement); and according to the java doc

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results.
>   In some (uncommon) situations, a single SQL statement may return
>   multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore
>   this unless you are (1) executing a stored procedure that you know may
>   return multiple results or (2) you are dynamically executing an
>   unknown SQL string. The execute method executes an SQL statement and
>   indicates the form of the first result. You must then use the methods
>   getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and
>   getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).

I think I was in the second case ("executing an unknown SQL string"), and the the exception was not thrown. When I called getMoreResults method from the debugger the exception was thrown.

I was able to workaround the problem by creating a [custom liquibase extension](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/tutorial-write-your-own-extension) where I validated the json using jackson library.